# Is there a method in PHP to use a varible as all or part of a classname?

Tags: php

Example

```php
$append = 'News';

class My_$append_Component {

}
```

The goal is to have a dynamic variable which changes the appended string based on folder names found in a directory.

Comment: No, class names are static. You can, however, dynamically reference an existing class name, or, you can dynamically create an anonymous class.

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @chris technically you can create one with eval, just saying. But note eval is evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use PHP to write a file that contains a class definition and then include or require that file.  The newly created class could have a name based on a variable.  So I think it's possible although I can't think of any reason you would want to do this.

Comment: That suggestion to write the file programmatically seems like the way to go. The class file is standard and all the methods remain the same, the only change is in the name, based on the folder name where it is located. For that reason I wanted to avoid continuously editing the file per folder just to change the name and figured I could store it in a variable, if such a method existed in PHP.

Comment: I'm curious of your use-case for this. Dave's solution is completely valid, but it is a "one-time setup" sort of solution, that usually would exist outside of your actual project. Why does the folder matter in the first place? PHP has namespaces that act as folders, and you can have the same class name in different namespaces. Also, if the methods are the same, why do you need multiple classes? Or, why aren't you at least using a base class?

Comment: If the methods remain the same then you're creating a new class with no new behaviour.  In that case it seems like you should be able to create an instance of an existing class and get the same result.  Please keep in mind that by creating classes at runtime you are making your code much more difficult to understand and debug among other things.  But maybe you find yourself in a very particular situation.  It would be helpful if you can explain the situation where you need to create a new class at runtime rather than just creating a new instance of an existing class.

Comment: @ChrisHaas and Dave S it is a bit lengthy to explain, so you may have to review the project at gitHub, and even collaborate to make it better. See https://github.com/WebsiteDons/elementor-widget-creator-library/tree/main/copy

It is a free library to allow easy and quick development of widgets for the WordPress page builder plugin called Elementor. It removes the need to write complex PHP coding for the control fields and instead uses an intuitive XML markup method.

Comment: @Nadal, that use-case actually seems to make sense, as far as I understand it. Thanks for giving into our curiosity! There's a lot of people here that are trying to do something the hard way because they just don't know better, and it is always nice to see the opposite!

Comment: @ChrisHaas if you use WordPress and familiar with the Elementor plugin, I'd certainly appreciate you trying the widget builder library and get involved in it's betterment as you see fit.  I have always preferred the simpler method of getting coding done, in fact I'll sometimes spend days trying to define simpler ways to get a repetitive process done (as in this case). I know my code writing method is not appealing to many seasoned authors (ie: no spacing between concats and brackets), however it is the only way I can read it with peace of mind.

Comment: @Nadal Thank you for the explanation.  I only took a quick look at your project and I've never used Elementor but I can't help but wonder, if the widget is defined by XML then why not create an instance of a single class and pass the XML into it?  You would use the contents of the XML file to implement methods like `getName()` in the widget.  So rather than `$mgr->register_widget_type(new $class())` it would be something like `$mgr->register_widget_type( new XML_Widget( $xml_content ) )`. Maybe the Elementor framework requires each widget to have its own class but I couldn't see that anywhere.

Comment: Similar to Dave's comments, I don't use Elementor either, but I would move 90% of that logic into an abstract class that sits between each individual class and the Elementor base class. That way all of your logic is still in one place. You could also use a trait for this, but I think that a base class makes more sense for this case.

Comment: @Nadal, I threw two PRs your way, feel free to accept or delete them as you please. I didn't test them, unfortunately, since I don't have Elementor, but I'm pretty confident that they are mostly accurate.

Comment: @DaveS and Chris Haas Elementor is a free plugin in case you wish to set it a dev environment. Yes, each widget must have a separate class as defined by Elem. Each widget must be registered in the Elem table hence the need for creating the pilot file in each widget folder and passing each new widget class to the `register_widget_type()` method via loop. See their dev guide at https://developers.elementor.com/creating-a-new-widget/ https://developers.elementor.com/add-custom-functionality/#Registering_New_Widgets

Comment: @ChrisHaas I see the advantage of using abstract class as you have written it. Thanks for that.

Comment: @Nadal I don't want to belabour the point but I looked at the dev guide and I don't see a requirement to have separate classes.  The text says "To add a new widget to Elementor we need to register the widget class" but the sample code does not register a class, it registers an instance: `\Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type( new \Elementor_Test_Widget1() );`  It looks like multiple widgets could be registered using separate instances of one class.  I think it simplifies things for you.  How do you modify a widget for example?  Do you need to delete the class?

Comment: @DaveS I always appreciate belaboring a point because it leads to perfection, and perfection matters. I haven't determined a working method to set a single widget class and use instances of that class to output a widget. I did attempt the `abstract{}` process defined by Chris Haas but it fails because it now requires loading all the Elem base classes (many). I looked at 2 top plugins that provide widgets for the Elem plugin, and all the widgets have different classnames and follows the same process of registration. No doubt there are methods to do this simpler, but I have not yet achieved it.